# Calculating covariance from three variances

Tags: variance, covariance, covariance-matrix

I have been asked to look to refactor some code.

There is a line shown below:

$\text{implied covariance} = -\frac{(\text{var}_1 - \text{var}_2 - \text{var}_3)} {2}$,

where $\text{var}_1$ is the implied variance of AUDUSD, $\text{var}_2$ is the implied variance of USDCAD and $\text{var}_3$ is the implied variance AUDCAD

I understand that this is a calculation of covariance between AUDCAD.

However I don't understand the $\text{var}_1 - \text{var}_2 - \text{var}_3$ line. I thought the covariance between two variables was the variance of the two variables multiplied together divided by $n-1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are effectively looking at is

$$\
\begin{align}
\log(S_{AUDCAD})&=\log(S_{AUDUSD})\pm\log(S_{USDCAD})\\
\Rightarrow  z&=x\pm y
\end{align}
$$
Thus,

$$
\sigma_z^2=\mathrm{E}\left(\left(x\pm y\right)^2\right)-
[\mathrm{E}(x\pm y)]^2
=\sigma_x^2+\sigma_y^2\pm 2\sigma_{xy}
$$
Hence,
$$
\tag{1}
\sigma_{xy}=\frac{\sigma_z^2-\sigma_x^2-\sigma_y^2}{\pm 2}
$$

Does that work for you?